# Text progressive light glow effect

Tags: jquery

Is there any jQuery plugin for  progressive light glow effect [like this](http://activeden.net/item/xml-text-progressive-light-glow-effect/47740)?

Comment: this is where flash excels... you *might* be able to do something like this with canvas

Comment: canvas...with Web Workers too..that is alot of processing work for javascript.

Comment: You could do individual letters, but even then it's not the same.

Comment: If you could find a way to create a layer with transparent text but an opaque background such that the letters "cut through" the background, you could sort-of get a similar effect.  However, I have no idea how to make a layer like that; as far as I can tell if you make a layer with a non-transparent background then that background shows through transparent text on the layer.

Comment: I played with slewing a blurred transparent png across some text but it just looks kind-of dumb.

Comment: @pointy, I think in this issue flash is the best solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw your post last night and it sounds like a good idea for a plugin to do. so I did it for you.

I have uploaded it [here](http://xgreen.co.uk/pages/miscprojects/textglow/textglow.htm)

Please note it needs the color animation plugin by John Resig which you can download [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color)

Comment: it is not canvas based. you could go towards that direction but you need to get into what typeface.js people did with re-rendering text in canvas over the normal text.

That is actually something I have done with my site and that is how the fonts have anti aliasing. 

but i wouldn't recommend it for this project as it will probably get too big and a simple glow effect should not be big.

Comment: maybe we can develop this further and create different effects too. I was thinking the random letter shine to create a sparkling effect would look cool too. :)

Comment: XGreen, Thanks for great plugin.
مرسی‌ :)

Comment: I have updated the plugin now to take two optional parameters: glow : true or sprakle : true

let me know if you can think of more effects for this.

Answer (score 0):

With canvas, and a *very* good computer, you would write something *like*, but not exactly what you linked.  To answer the question: **no**, I've never seen anything remotely like that, and have seem a very wide variety of plugins.

The best you could hope for would be a linear fade or an image behind a text path that slides across.  I've never *seen* anything like this in javascript, because it's so specialized, it'd be better to make an animated image (honestly, for a color pallete that small a dithered `.gif` may look pretty good).

Either use flash if you want the effect to be *that* fancy (no alternative is going to do it *that* well, you can only hope to get something satisfactory, but not that level of color accuracy and smoothness at once)...or make an animated image.  In short, a browser's rendering engine isn't optimized for that kind of animation or image swapping, if a `.gif` is enough because you have 1 image to do this with, that's your best bet, otherwise: flash.